# Best way to call external API's one for getting token and other for fetching details with token using node js lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, axios, node.js-got

```
const got = require('got');   
 var config = {
      url: '/authorization/tokenrequest',
      body: data,
      // method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
      }
    }

module.exports.hello = async() => {
  const response = await got.post(config).then(ok => {
    console.log(ok.body);
    var parsedJson = JSON.parse(ok.body);
    if(parsedJson.Value.Success){
      var token = 'Bearer ' + parsedJson.Value.AuthenticationToken;
      
      var data = JSON.stringify({"userid","test"});
      var configs = {
        method: 'post',
        url: '/user/userprofile',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer 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', 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        data : data
      };

      console.log(configs);
      const userResponse = got.post(configs).then(ok => {
      console.log(ok.userResponse);
      var userResponseJson = JSON.parse(ok.userResponse);
      console.log(userResponseJson);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
  }).catch(reject);
}
```

Getting below error
HTTPError: Response code 500 (Internal Server Error)
at Request.request.once (\node_modules\got\dist\source\as-promise\index.js:117:42)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

Best way to fetch token and then use it in another end point in node js.

Comment: are you using a third party service or your own API has a `/authorization/tokenrequest` endpoint ? In both case, the full URL is needed in your code to access the endopoint

Comment: Yep accessing the end point is not the problem, i want to know what is the best way to execute this? Like using promise or what could be the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

You may write something like this. You can get a instance from ApiInstance class. You can reach getUserProfile function which is async and promise structured. You don't always need to run token function with this structure. You can also add token expire date check for it. This structure also enable encapsualtion. I hope, you mean something like this and it helps.

```
const apiInstance = new ApiInstance();

module.exports.hello = async () => {
  const data = '';
  let userProfile;

  try {
    userProfile = await apiInstance.getUserProfile(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }

  if (userProfile) {
    console.info('User Profile:', userProfile);
  } else {
    console.info('User profile not found!');
  }
}

function ApiInstance() {
  const got = require('got');
  let token = null;

  const getToken = async () => {

    if (token) {
      return token;
    } else {
      const data = '';
      const config = {
        url: '/authorization/tokenrequest',
        body: data,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
      }

      return got.post(config)
        .then(response => {
          return JSON.parse(response.body).Value.AuthenticationToken;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
          return null;
        })
    }
  }

  this.getUserProfile = async (data) => {
    token = await getToken();
    const config = {
      method: 'post',
      url: '/user/userprofile',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      data: data
    };

    return got.post(config)
      .then(response => response.userResponse)
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        return null;
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.